# How to pass location as extra

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-location, android-bundle

I am trying to pass a `android.location;` to an activity as a bundled extra.  the Location class `implements Parcelable` so i thought i could just use

```
intent.putExtra(String name,Parcelable value)
```

but it won't let me for some reason..

```
Location _latestlocal; // is set by my location manager;
```

but when i write

```
i.putExtra("location", _latestLocal);
```

it gives me the error:

> The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not
>   applicable for the arguments (KNAugmentedRealityActivity.extras,
>   Location)

am i missing something?

Comment: The issue seems to be with the first parameter of the `putExtra`, not with the `Location`. Are you sure the first parameter is indeed the `String` "location"?

Comment: oh my god.. i am so stupid.. thanks.. i was actually using an enum and not a string and forgot to call .name()  thanks!!